# Parallelise list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have and dictionary that contain stock names and price and also exponential moving average periods as:

```
stock_data = dict()
stock_data['AOT_day'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
stock_data['AOT_week'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
ema_periods = [2, 3]
```

I have calculate ema by use dictionary comprehension :

```
ema_dict = dict((key, dict((period, ema(stock_data[key], period)) for period in ema_periods)) for key in stock_data.keys())
```

my result:

```
>>>> {'AOT_day': {2: ['nan', '37.62', '38.04', '38.18', '38.39'], 3: ['nan', 'nan', '37.83', '38.04', '38.27']}, 'AOT_week': {2: ['nan', '37.62', '36.21', '36.40', '37.30'], 3: ['nan', 'nan', '36.92', '36.71', '37.23']}}
```

After that i try to make it parallel for test the time elaspe but my output is wrong

mycode:

```
def gen_ema(stock_data, key, periods):
    result = dict((period, ema(stock_data[key], period)) for period in periods)
    return result

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(gen_ema)(stock_data, key, ema_periods) for key in stock_data.keys())
```

my result:

```
>>>> [{2: ['nan', '37.62', '38.04', '38.18', '38.39'], 3: ['nan', 'nan', '37.83', '38.04', '38.27']}, {2: ['nan', '37.62', '36.21', '36.40', '37.30'], 3: ['nan', 'nan', '36.92', '36.71', '37.23']}]
```

I try to make the second result same as first result but I confused.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `Parallel`?

Comment: The result is the same, you're simply missing the keys `AOT_day` and `AOT_week`.  Also, it looks like there might be something wrong with your parentheses in your multi-processing approach.